# No puedo enviar datos desde Ionic Angular hacia un POST en PHP

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

llevo un rato tratando de enviar datos desde Angular en Ionic hacia un PHP Post hosteado, he aqui el codigo.
Tengo la clase usuario que lleva esta estructura:

```
export class Usuario {

    constructor(
        public nombre: string,
        public apellidos: string, 
        public numtelefono: string,
        public categoria: string,
        public oficio: string,
        public calificacion: string,
        public edad: string,
        public imagen: string
    ){}
}
```

Creo un objeto de usuario para almacenar los datos manualmente:

```
user = new Usuario('Julio','Perez','6182121313','1','2','4','25','julio.jpg');
```

Aqui es donde se llama el primer metodo, el cual enviara los datos a la otra clase para el post:

```
        onSubmit(){
          this.userService.enroll(this.user)
            .subscribe(
              data => console.log('Exito! ', data),
              error => console.error('Error!', error)
            )
          }
```

y en el servicio realizo esto:

```
enroll( user : Usuario){
  console.log(user);
  return this.http.post(this.url, user,this.httpOptions);
}
```

Al parecer si hace la consulta, es decir envia el objeto pero me aparecen errores como estos:

> tab1.page.ts:54 Error! HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders,
>   status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url:
>   "http://antraxsw.000webhostapp.com/add.php", ok: false, …}

Aun que si en la parte de enroll() agrego por ejemplo user.nombre me regresa la respuesta json correctamente.

Comment: Sin tener más detalles es complicado saber qué está pasando. ¿No pone nada más en la consola?

Comment: ¿Cómo generas la respuesta en `add.php`? ¿Has probado a mirar el inspector de red para ver qué devuelve la llamada XHR (código HTTP, cabeceras y contenido de la respuesta)?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Dicho esto, aunque tu código en typescript es detallado, falta la parte que genera el problema, la parte en PHP. Sin ella no podremos ayudarte a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Elimine las condiciones en la parte del Add.php, esto con el fin de probar solamente datos string en la base de datos, la parte de la imagen la puse en POST como ya dije, solamente para probar.

```
        <?php 

        include 'apitrabajadores.php';

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");

        $api = new apiTrabajadores();



        //insertar datos
        $item = array(
            'nombre'=>$_POST['nombre'],
            'apellidos'=>$_POST['apellidos'],
            'numtelefono'=>$_POST['numtelefono'],
            'categoria'=>$_POST['categoria'],
            'oficio'=>$_POST['oficio'],
            'calificacion'=>$_POST['calificacion'],
            'edad'=>$_POST['edad'],
            'imagen'=> $_POST['imagen']
        );
        $api->add($item);    ?>
```

He hecho pruebas con el Postman y si envia los datos y los inserta correctamente, al parecer no reconoce bien los valores al llegar al Add.php o no se envian correctamente desde el metodo post en angular